# I have a button whose background I want to be transparent in Android

Tags: android

I have to make a buttons background transparent, how do I go about it?

I know there is a constant transparent which I found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html#transparent), but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: is it image button or simple button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set below property in xml file where you declare your button.

```
android:background="@color/android:transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

for set Transparent background color for button use this.

```
Button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```